# How do mongodb aggregation framework pipelines work?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the mongodb aggregation framework pipelines work.  My expectation is that each step consumes the output of the preceding step.  Here is a concrete example using the sample collection provided at http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json :

```
> db.zipcodes.aggregate({$match:{state:"CA"}});
```

produces results such as these.

```
    {
        "city" : "TRUCKEE",
        "loc" : [
            -120.295031,
            39.319321
        ],
        "pop" : 199,
        "state" : "CA",
        "_id" : "96162"
    }
```

so far so good.  Then I decide to add another step to get a projection of the above, by running:

```
> db.zipcodes.aggregate({
    $match:{state:"CA"}, 
    $project: {city: 1, pop: 1, state: 1}
});
```

The projection works but ignores the first $match step.  It is based on the original input, and includes documents in which state != CA:

```
    {
        "city" : "THAYNE",
        "pop" : 505,
        "state" : "WY",
        "_id" : "83127"
    }
```

Is my expectation misplaced or have I been staring at a syntax issue without seeing it?  I am running version 2.2.0:

```
> db.version();
2.2.0
```

The exemple queries seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntax issue, you're doing:

```
db.zips.aggregate({$match:{state:"CA"}, $project: {city: 1, pop: 1, state: 1}})
```

... with both fields, $match and $project, in the same document. The aggregate command takes a series of distinct documents describing the stages of the pipeline:

```
db.zips.aggregate({$match:{state:"CA"}}, {$project: {city: 1, pop: 1, state: 1}})
```

Apparently, if you put several fields in a pipeline stage, MongoDB only uses the last one. This is a bug that's been fixed on the next development branch: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6861